# Class implemented in app target and test target

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, cocoapods

I'm using CoreData and have extended the automatic (didn't generate custom class files) model classes by custom variables that return objects of classes coming from an CocoaPods dependency.

```
import Foundation
import ACocoaPodsFramework
import CoreData

extension MyClass {
    var customVar: AClassFromCocoaPods? {
        return AClassFromCocoaPods()
    }
}
```

I've added a target for unit tests to the Xcode project and added MyClass and the xcdatamodeld to the test target. A test class looks like the following.

```
import XCTest
import ACocoaPodsFramework
import CoreData
@testable import MyAppTarget

class MyClassTests: XCTestCase {
}
```

I have imported ACocoaPodsFramework in both the app and the unit test target as a framework.

When i run the unit tests i receive the following notice

```
objc[21178]: Class MyClass is implemented in both /.../MyAppTarget.app/MyAppTarget (0x1017703f0) and /... MyAppTarget.app/PlugIns/MyClassTests.xctest/MyClassTests (0x123dc8ae8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

and exception

```
Could not cast value of type 'MyAppTarget.MyClass' (0x60c0000ccc60) to 'MyAppTargetTests.MyClass' (0x1258c9a20).
```

Comment: Do you only see this warning or do you get any errors as well?

Comment: i added the exception to the question

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by removing **all** app files from the test target and instead importing the needed app files in the test classes using

```
@testable import MyAppTarget
```